# why my test fails

Tags: rspec2

models/question_spec.rb

```
context "title" do
 subject { Question.new(title: 'is it valid question ?') }

  it { should be_valid }
end
```

models/question.rb

```
validates :title , presence: true , :length => { :minimum   => 15, :maximum   => 160 }
validates_length_of :body, :minimum => 250
```

result

```
Question title 
 Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
 expected valid? to return true, got false
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

First: minimum and maximum are switched.

Second: u didnt specify a body for the question.

Comment: I  want Question.body to be optional . how can i do it then ?

Comment: Its not optional. Its just your test that doesnt set a valid value for body. Try to set a valid body inside your subject body.

Comment: still. Your test is wrong man. try to use [https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers](shoulda-matchers). It will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Test is failing because `Question` `body` is setting nil. To accept nil with numerablity validation , we have to use `allow_nil: true` . so the final validation statement will be

```
validates_length_of :body, :minimum => 250, :allow_nil => true
```